# Django OneToOneField & Foreignkey - How to get value from related model?

Tags: python, django

I've been banging my head against this for an whole workday now and tried various suggestions from stackoverflow and other google results, and consulted the django documentation but all to no avail.

In my django project I have the two models listed below. The related values in the models are the rowid which is unique to each "Sag". My goal is that when I query using "*Sag.objects.all()*" that it would also return the group attached to that specific rowid.
Ideally it should be a "OneToOneField" and not a "ForeignKey" since the rowid should only exists once in both tables but my latest try had me change it to a "ForeignKey". I have, however, been unable to get the related field with the different solutions I've tried so far

```
class Sag(models.Model):
id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=False, primary_key=True)
rowid = models.IntegerField(db_column='RowId', blank=True, null=True)
posts = models.TextField(db_column='POSTS', blank=True, null=True)
date = models.TextField(db_column='Date', blank=True, null=True)
art = models.IntegerField(db_column='Art', blank=True, null=True)

class Grouping(models.Model):
rowid = models.ForeignKey(Sag, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='RowId')
group = models.IntegerField(db_column='Group', blank=True, null=True)
```

Any ideas/ressources as to how i would solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a `ForeignKey` as you have it here, you can pass a [related_name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name). If you don't pass one, Django assigns one by default with the model name and then `_set`, here it would be `sag.grouping_set.all()`.

```
sag = Sag.objects.get(id=1)
groupings = sags.grouping_set.all()
```

Inside a template, if you have a list of Sags:

```
{% for sag in sags %}
    {% for grouping in sag.grouping_set.all %}
        {{ grouping.group }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

To grab the values only:

```
sag_groups = Sag.objects.all().values('posts', 'data', 'art', 'grouping_set__group')
```

With a [OneToOneField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/) you could do something similar:

```
sag = Sag.objects.get(id=1)
grouping = sag.grouping
grouping_group = grouping.group
```

Inside a template:

```
{% for sag in sags %}
    {{ sag.posts }}

    {{ sag.grouping.group }}
    {{ sag.grouping.rowid}}
{% endfor %}
```

For the values only:

```
sag_groups = Sag.objects.all().values('posts', 'data', 'art', 'grouping__group')
```